# Intellij Idea a simple file watcher for copying a file from one directory to another

Tags: intellij-idea, file-watcher

I want a file watcher for Intellij Idea which would copy my file from one directory to another after I modified it.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried and what doesn't work for you. It should be straightforward. What OS do you use? How do you call the copy command? It may be a shell command, so you need to run the shell as the app and pass all the rest as the parameters.

Comment: I solved it with cat command

Comment: This is a common need, I'm surprised it is no a standard watcher.  @AlexPo, can you be more precise as regards implementation with cat ?

Comment: @patb I added my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

[image]

I used `Program` `cat` then specified `Argument` as FileName macro, `Output paths to refresh` like where to save output. Then I set `Create output file from stdout`.